# Asking for tips on how to debug envoy for kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, networking, envoyproxy

I want to use envoy as my kubernetes deployment service proxy, and my application uses grpc to communicate with client-side.

My steps:

1. Write a yaml file for envoy configuration.

Envoy configuration:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: http_listener
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8080 }
      filter_chains:
      - filters:
        - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
            codec_type: auto
            stat_prefix: ingress_http
            route_config:
              name: local_route
              virtual_hosts:
                - name: local_service
                  domains: [ "*" ]
                  routes:
                    - match:
                        { prefix: "/" }
                      route:
                        cluster: my_app_prod_service
                        timeout: 30s
                        max_grpc_timeout: 30s
                  cors:
                    allow_origin_string_match:
                      - safe_regex: { regex: ".*", google_re2: { } }
                    allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                    allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                    max_age: "1728000"
                    expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
            http_filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
    - name: my_app_prod_service
      connect_timeout: 0.5s
      type: strict_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: my_app_prod_service
        endpoints:
        - lb_endpoints:
          - endpoint:
              address:
                socket_address:
                  address: my-app-service-staging
                  port_value: 30015
```

2. Deploy it as config map.

```
kubectl create configmap envoy-config-prod \
  --from-file=envoy_config_prod.yaml \
  -o yaml --dry-run=client | kubectl replace --force -f -
```

3. Deploy envoy deployment and service, and mount the config map.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: envoy-server-prod
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: envoy-server-prod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: envoy-server-prod
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: envoy-server-prod
          image: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.18.2
          args:
            - -c
            - /etc/envoy/envoy_config_prod.yaml
            - --log-path
            - /tmp/envoy_info.log
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
          - name: envoy-admin
            containerPort: 9901
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 5
              memory: 5Gi
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/envoy
              name: envoy-config-prod
      volumes:
        - name: envoy-config-prod
          configMap:
            name: envoy-config-prod
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: envoy-service-prod
  labels:
    app: envoy-service-prod
spec:
  selector:
    app: envoy-server-prod
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
  externalIPs:
    - 10.1.4.63
```

4. Make a headless service and its deployment.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-service-staging
  labels:
    app: my-app-service-staging
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: grpc
      port: 30015
      targetPort: 30015
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-app-deploy-staging
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-deploy-staging
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app-deploy-staging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app-deploy-staging
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app-deploy-staging
        image: $IMAGE_SHA
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 2G
            cpu: 1
```

I checked that in the envoy deployment, `/etc/envoy/envoy_config_prod.yaml` and `/tmp/envoy_info.log` both exist, and I don't see error messages in it.

I tried to make http connections to envoy service, hoping it to transfer it to my application deployment.

```
> curl -v 10.1.4.63:8080
*   Trying 10.1.4.63:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 10.1.4.63 port 8080 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 10.1.4.63 port 8080: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.1.4.63 port 8080: Connection timed out
```

But it just time outs.

I tried to get the services and deployments.

```
> k get svc
my-app-service-staging       ClusterIP   None            <none>        30015/TCP   3h54m
envoy-service-prod           ClusterIP   10.43.157.121   10.1.4.63     8080/TCP    6h55m

> k get deploy
my-deploy-deploy-staging        1/1     1            1           29d
```

I'm wondering, how should debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Envoy supports a wide range of timeouts that may need to be configured depending on the deployment. [Configure timeouts](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/faq/configuration/timeouts.html?highlight=failed%20connect%20connection%20timeout) summarize the most important timeouts used in various scenarios.

Refer to [Debug Envoy Proxy](https://layer5.io/blog/envoy/debug-envoy-proxy).

Please go through this similar [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74555950/field-connect-timeout-is-missing-in-name-service-envoyproxy-io) & [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68865578/failed-to-connect-to-port-8080-connection-timed-out), which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi, I suspect my issue is a connection issue: I cannot curl to my deployment, rather than a timeout one. My reasoning is: the curl timeout after several minutes, rather than a few seconds, which is the timeout value I set. Do you think that make sense to you?